# With three.js, how do I extrude a cylinder out of a SphereGeometry?

Tags: three.js

I've got a THREE.SphereGeometry. What I'd like to do is have the user point to a given part of it, project a circle and then on user input extrude from the sphere a cylinder with the same radius of the circle and height proportional to what the user input is. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having some redundant triangles and unseen object intersections, why not just add a new Mesh using `THREE.CylinderGeometry` to the scene, and color it to match the sphere (much easier than trying to modify the sphere geometry)? You could place it relative to Sphere's origin and then use `sphere.add(cylinder)` instead of `scene.add(cyclinder)` so that the new cyclinder mesh always stays put relative to that sphere.

To deal with the "pointing at the sphere surface" part of the problem, look at the THREE.js `Raycaster` examples. Use a raycaster to determine where they are pointing, and then just draw from there.

Comment: Problem with that is when people want to "punch" the sphere instead of extuding; also, the whole thing would have a texture that would probably look a bit bad

Comment: well then you have not defined the problem very clearly, eh? In such a case, I suggest that the primitives you will need to draw the geometry, and the primitives you need to represent such geometry, are not entirely the same. You should think about the operations you need at a high level and then tesselate on the fly.